# UIPickerView selectRow doesn't works

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I try to select a row in my PickerView but it doesn't works. It stays at the first row.

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIDatePicker!

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return 10
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!{
    return String(row + 1)
}


//In viewDidLoad
pickerView.selectRow(6, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

The pickerView is working well it shows 1 to 10 but the selectRow doesn't works.

It should select the sixth row but it stays on the first one.

Comment: Double check if your `IBOutlet` is correctly bound

Comment: BTW: Isn't viewDidLoad a bit too early from the architecture point of view..? It'd be probably better to select row on viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear. I think that your code can have now invalid order, did you check what gets called 1st?

Comment: I have double checked that the IBOutlet i correctly bound and yes it is. Also i tried changing viewDidLoad with viewWillAppear but it still doesn't works

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While inside the `viewDidLoad` method, your picker is empty. Since there is no 6th element to pick, it doesn't pick it.

You can do this if you delay execution of the select call until after the data is finished loading. Likely one cycle will be enough.

First though, try moving your select to `viewDidAppear`.

Good luck!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Keep in mind, while in the viewDidLoad method, numberOfRowsInComponent hasn't been called, nor has titleForRow. That's why the picker is still empty. It was only just loaded after all. 