# change initial row pickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180995/uipickerview-selectrow-doesnt-works) that you have to use `pickerView.selectRow` inside `viewDidAppear()`. While `pickerView.selectRow` is working inside `func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` it does not work in `viewDidAppear()`.

I just want to set the initial row to another row than 0

What am I missing here?

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let scrollerOfset = 100
    var kiloMeters = [Int](-100...200)

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerActive: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        pickerView.selectRow(scrollerOfset, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }

}
```

Xcode gives this error

> Cannot invoke 'selectRow' with an argument list of type '(Int, inComponent: Int, animated: Bool)'
>   at line 32 (in `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)`)

## Update

Code changed to this to make it work:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let scrollerOfset = 100
    var kiloMeters = [Int](-100...200)

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerActive: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        picker.selectRow(scrollerOfset, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add the code that you used? Without that it is difficult to figure out what does not work.

Comment: give it a try : `pickerView.selectRow(scrollerOfset, inComponent: 0, animated: true);` check if scrollerOfset not nill, or check with some hard value like 5 or 10

Comment: nope :( same error. Error is btw: "Cannot invoke 'selectRow' with an argument list of type '(Int, inComponent: Int, animated: Bool)'"

Comment: did you try like this: `pickerView.selectRow(5, inComponent: 0, animated: true);`

Comment: try to add this line in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yea, I tried before and again just now, it doesn't work either :(

Comment: it sounds so easy.... Just change the initial row of the picker view...

Comment: Do you need to include `UIPickerViewDataSource` too as well as the delegate? Could it be this which is stopping it from working? Also, where are you defining pickerView in `viewDidAppear`? Doesn't seem to be defined anywhere?

Comment: how do I define pickerView in viewDidAppear?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a noob question @Darren but I really don't understand it, and it will probably help me out :)

Comment: I've got a meeting for a few hours, but will try and put what I have as code when I get back ... we are all noobs (just of different levels!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are missing the declaration of `pickerView` property in your class, try declare it with under `pickerActive`, like

```
  @IBOutlet weak var pickerActive: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
```

Then connect it thru IB like `pickerActive`

Comment: Thanks, I understand in now :)