# Selecting a row in a UIPickerView - swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to select a row of a picker view in Swift.I know there are other questions like this but they all have the same answers which doesn't work for me. Such questions can be located at : [UIPickerView selectRow doesn't works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180995/uipickerview-selectrow-doesnt-works) .

They all point to use this code in the `viewDidAppear` :

```
 pickerview.selectRow(3, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

But the View Controller still looks like this: [image: simulator]

Any ideas on how to select a row?

Comment: Have you set `pickerview.dataSource = self` and `pickerview.delegate = self` or connected them in a storyboard?

Comment: remove the pickerValue condition and direct use pickerview.selectRow(3, inComponent: 0, animated: true) and try.

Comment: Reload datas before use this code.

Comment: @DHShah01 I connected them in Story Board.

Comment: @JP_Mob It's definitely running the code because I added a print Statement to check.

Comment: @PREMKUMAR how should I reload the data?

Comment: I dont think so reload will work @PREMKUMAR because he need third row selected when picker launch, I am not able to see print out of condition,just comment once whole viewdidappair code and try to print because same code working fine for me

Comment: @JP_Mob What code is working for you?

Comment: It looks like you only have 3 elements in your picker. Pickerview element rows are 0-indexed, so instead of `pickerview.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)`, `pickerview.selectRow(2, inComponent: 0, animated: true)`, `pickerview.selectRow(3, inComponent: 0, animated: true)`, you'll want `pickerview.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)`, `pickerview.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)`, `pickerview.selectRow(2, inComponent: 0, animated: true)`

Comment: Thanks @DHShah01 That works great! Please fill that in as the answer

Comment: No problem. Happy coding! @NiallKehoe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you only have 3 elements in your picker. Pickerview element rows are 0-indexed, so instead of

```
pickerview.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
pickerview.selectRow(2, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
pickerview.selectRow(3, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

you'll want

```
pickerview.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
pickerview.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
pickerview.selectRow(2, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```